# Chapter title missing in header on odd pages and header margin very small when using KOMA script

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I am using the KOMA script class `scrbook` for a thesis and would like to get a two-side layout. In the header of each page I would like to have the chapter name included alternating on the left and right side (opposite side of the binding). When I set up a document like this:

```
\documentclass[
a5paper,
twoside,
fontsize=11pt,
listof=totoc
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\KOMAoptions{BCOR=15mm}
\chapter{Chaptername}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: PDF output of minimal working example]

Here the chapter name is missing on the odd page. Also the header appears to be very close to the top of the page.

How can I fix these two issues?

Comment: I would recommend to set `BCOR=15mm` in the document preamble, before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke thanks for your recommendation. I used KOMAoptions because for the title page I used the geometry package to reduce page margins which breaks the KOMA layout. So after the title page I use the KOMAoptions to restore the KOMA layout. I don't know if this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: An titlepage usualy uses the typing area of the book, a book cover uses other typing area. To keep things clear I use a separate file to create the book cover.

Comment: @Axel This would be another question. If you have additional questions, please ask them if you cannot find a similar one. However, if you use `\maketitle` you can declare the first title page to be a cover page with different margins (see `titlepage=fistiscover` the KOMA-Script manual for more information). If not, you can use option `usegeometry`. Then you can use `geometry`'s commands to change the margins and to switch back. Or you can use `typearea`'s commands to store the area settings and to restore them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different possibilitys. One is to change your line

```
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

to

```
\usepackage[%
  headsepline,
  automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles % <==============================================
\ohead{\leftmark} % <==================================================
\ihead{\pagemark} % <==================================================
```

With `ohead` you define the content of the outer part of headline (chapter name), with `ihead` you can define the inner part of header line (I used the page number here).

With the complete code

```
\documentclass[%
  a5paper,
  twoside,
  fontsize=11pt,
  listof=totoc
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[%
  headsepline,
  automark
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles % <==============================================
\ohead{\leftmark} % <==================================================
\ihead{\pagemark} % <==================================================
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\KOMAoptions{BCOR=15mm}
\chapter{Chaptername}
\blindtext
\section{Sectionname}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

and

[image]

To reflect your additional questions in the comment you can use the following code. To get the page number on the first page of a chapter etc. too (good typography if page number is in the foot) use command `cfoot*` (the `*` changes the style `plain` for first chapter page, TOC etc. too). I also moves `BCOR` into the class options.

```
\documentclass[%
  a5paper,
  twoside,
  fontsize=11pt,
  DIV=11,         % 11 8 to change the margins and typing area <========
  BCOR=15mm,      % binding correction
  headsepline,    % for header, activates headinclude <=================
  listof=totoc
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % <=======================================
\clearpairofpagestyles % <==============================================
\ohead{\leftmark} % <===================================================
\cfoot*{\pagemark} % <==================================================

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chaptername}
\blindtext
\section{Sectionname}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help!